# Why does my TextBox get focused when clicking inside of ScrollViewer?

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime

In my Windows Store app, I've created a ScrollViewer (with a Grid inside) with a few TextBoxes inside. Whenever the user clicks anywhere within the ScrollViewer, the first TextBox is focused. I have no idea why this happens, and it certainly is not the behavior I want.

Is this just a symptom of XAML trying to be "helpful"? How do I prevent it?

**Edit**: I found a clue. This only occurs when my TextBoxes are inside of a ScrollViewer. It also occurs on both C++ and C# projects, so it's obviously a symptom of XAML/WinRT. Adding example XAML:

With the following XAML, if I focus the second TextBox and then click anywhere in the margin between the boxes, the first TextBox is automatically focused. I don't want it to be focused.

```
<ScrollViewer Background="#111111"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
  <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
      <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" />
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: "Border with a few TextBoxes inside"?? A Border can have only one child element... 
Can you share your XAML code?

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. It's a Border with a Grid with a few TextBoxes spread across different cells. I'll edit my question to clarify.

Comment: I've posted my XAML now along with a fresh clue -- it looks like it only happens when a TextBox is inside a ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found a solution! Setting the ScrollViewer's `TabStop="true"` prevents this behavior.

Comment: I've got the same problem but can't find a tabstop function on my scrollviewer. Can you explain where I can find it?
AHHH got it. It's called IsTabStop and works like a charm. Thx!

Comment: Had this problem also with a UWP page, works a treat.