# How can you keep focus when pressing a disabled button in a scrolviewer in xaml?

Tags: xaml, uwp-xaml, c++-cx

When creating a default C++ xaml blank app for UWP from visual studio add the following code in the xaml page.

```
       <ScrollViewer>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox Height="20"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Height="800"></TextBox>
                <Button Content="Enabled" IsEnabled="True"></Button>
                <Button Content="Disabled" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
```

If I put the focus on the Enabled button and after that I press the disabled button the focus shifts to the first TextBox.

I found a workaround, to add a 0 dimension focusable element as the first element of the stack panel. `<Button Width="0" Height="0"></Button>`

But this will affect the other children. ( The id will be changed by 1 )

Do you know a more elegant way of keeping the focus on the previous element after pressing a disabled button in a panel from a scollviewer?

The behavior is not present if the stackpanel is not in a scrollviewer.

Comment: Duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14490901/why-does-my-textbox-get-focused-when-clicking-inside-of-scrollviewer/15559383

Comment: Is your this issue resolved by just setting the `IsTabStop` property?

Comment: Partially. Using IsTabStop changed the focus from the first element to the ScrollViewer. I would want the same behaviour as in https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rrodbE . The focus to be unchanged ( remain on the last focused element )

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically change the app's focus in the `ScrollViewer`'s Tapped event.

In the xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer Tapped="ScrollViewer_Tapped">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Height="20"></TextBox>
        <TextBox Height="200"></TextBox>
        <Button Content="Enabled"  x:Name="EnableButton"></Button>
        <Button Content="Disabled" IsEnabled="False"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

In the xaml.cpp, handle the `ScrollViewer_Tapped` event to make the `EnableButton` get focus.

```
void CApp::MainPage::ScrollViewer_Tapped(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::Input::TappedRoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    EnableButton->Focus(Windows::UI::Xaml::FocusState::Programmatic);
}
```

If you have any other Controls who can get focus, you should also handle their similar event to assign the focus.

Comment: I need the focus to go on the last focused element, not a specific element. I know how to do it if I have access to all the children. On GetFocus to mark who got focus and on tap to focus on that one. I only have access to the ScrollViewer, the panel and the disabled button. I also would want to make a difference between when the disabled button was pressed. Like if the disable button id is pressed do nothing to the focus, if only the scrollviewer is pressed focus the scrollviewer.

Comment: I can have multiple ScrollViewer and each should keep track of the last focused child. I wonder if there is a simpler method that keeping a DependencyProperty in the ScrollViewer of it's last focused child. A flag or a simple event callback.

Comment: Since you press the disabled button in the ScrollViewer, the ScrollViewer will get focus. You can use a variable to record the last focused one, then make it focus when you click the ScrollViewer' area where it can not get focus on.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that doesn't require each child element to have a GotFocus where it should register as the last focused element. Something that I can change directly in the ScrollViewer. ( if it was possible to have the scvrollviewer notified directly what child got the focus, not by the child )

Comment: The UWP page is different from the webpage. There is a ScrollViewer in the bottom of all the controls, if you click the disabled button, the ScrollViewer will get focus. This is the required behavior in uwp. Maybe there are some other alternative to achieve your real requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. On [PointerPressed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointerpressed) get the [current focused element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager.getfocusedelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_FocusManager_GetFocusedElement) as an UIElement^ and [capture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.capturepointer) [the pointer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.pointerroutedeventargs.pointer#Windows_UI_Xaml_Input_PointerRoutedEventArgs_Pointer)